# SystemVerilog: proper place to put interfaces

Tags: system-verilog

I'm wondering if there's a recommended or standard way in which people arrange Interfaces for design in their projects. My project (simplified):

```
top
top.sv
--includes
----my_intf.sv
----my_pkg.sv
----my_defines.sv
--sub1
----sub1.sv
--sub2
----sub2.sv
```

I have functions and parameters inside my_pkg.sv:

```
`include "my_defines.sv"
package my_pkg;
parameter SETTING1 = 5;
parameter SETTING2 = 6;

typedef logic [SETTING1-1:0] my_type1_t;
typedef logic [SETTING2-1:0] my_type2_t;

function my_type1_t sub(input my_type1_t a, b);
  return a - b;
endfunction
endpackage
```

And my_intf.sv:

```
interface data_if #(
  parameter type data_t
);

logic vld;
logic ray;
logic data_t data;

modport src(
  output vld, data,
  input rdy
);
modport dst(
  input vld, data,
  output rdy
);
endinterface
```

My question is, should I  `` `include my_intf.SystemVerilog ``? What happens when I `include them in multiple design modules? What happens if my_intf.sv uses a definition inside my_pkg.sv? If I include my_pkg.sv inside my_intf.sv, my_pkg.sv will be included multiple times (which causes a warning).

What's everyone's preferred arrangement with this stuff?

Answer (score 2):

Interfaces get compiled just like modules—just once and in any order. Packages must be compiled before they can be imported. Virtual interface references are the one exception with use in packages that you don't have to compile the interface.

You should set up your compile so that everything only gets compiled once. And the only exception to that rule is macro definition files. You can  `` `include `` them where needed as long as you put compile guards around them. By try to limit that as it still needs to parse the entire file for every include.

Comment: Thanks. How do I access an interface file from individual modules without doing an include in every one?

Comment: Don't know what tool you are using, but you can place it in an interface folder just like you did with sub1.

Comment: I’m using VCS but also Verilator. Are you saying I can specify the directory with -y and not include it in any module file?

Comment: You haven't shown any compile commands. Just treat your interface like a module.

Comment: Cmd: vcs +notimingchecks +nospecify -sverilog +v2k -full64 -l vcs.log -ntb_opts -kdb +libext+.sv+.v+.svh+.vh -f filelist.f

Comment: filelist.f: -y sub1/ -y sub2/ -y includes/ +incdir+ includes/ top.sv -top top

Comment: I only know Modelsim/Questa command lines. If the interface is instantiated in a module, then just like a module instantiation, it will search the -y directory for the interface definition. If that doesn't work for you, then put the file explicitly in the filelist.f